# Input Empty String In NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

```
    app.post('/register',function(req,res){
    var user=req.body.username;
    var pass=req.body.password;
    var bool = new Boolean(false);

for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    //if((JSON.stringify(values[i].usernames).toLowerCase==JSON.stringify(user).toLowerCase))
    if(values[i].usernames==user){
      console.log(values[i].usernames)
      console.log(user)
      bool=true;
    }
  }

  if(bool==true||user==""||pass==""){
    console.log("Sorry the username already exists")
    res.status(400).send({ Error: 'The Username Already Exists' })
  }else{
        values.push(
            {usernames : user,
            passwords : pass
          })
          
          console.log(values);
          var json = JSON.stringify(values);
          fs.writeFileSync("users.json",json);
          res.redirect('/register')
        }
          });
```

I want to check if the user is trying to input a empty string in the registration page but it always fails to catch this error and I have tried several methods and the the same problem appears again

Comment: Are you sure the values you are sending are empty? How have you verified that?

Comment: I register without typing any input in the fields and print the user value in the console

Comment: For one, `if(bool==true)` is pointless, use `if(bool)`.  Terrible name, too.

Comment: it won't solve the problem though

Comment: @punund: `if (bool)` will only work as expected if they also initialize the value as `var bool = false`. `if(new Boolean(false))` will be true.

Comment: What does `console.log(user, user.length, pass, pass.length)` print?

Comment: `if(values[i].usernames==user){` you realize this will always be false, don't you?

Comment: [ { usernames: '', passwords: '' } ]
 0  0. this is the output of the print statement

Comment: Here's how I know to find out if it's empty or filled `if (typeof (user) === 'string' && (user.trim()).length) // contains some string`

Answer (score 0):

Split condition check for every variable, maybe its look like :

```
if (!bool) {
  console.log("Sorry the username already exists")
  res.status(400).send({ Error: 'The Username Already Exists' })
}

if (!user || user.length < 1) {
  console.log("Sorry the username already exists")
  res.status(400).send({ Error: 'The Username Already Exists' })
}

if (!pass || pass.length < 1) {
  console.log("Sorry the username already exists")
  res.status(400).send({ Error: 'The Username Already Exists' })
}
```